# Passing parameters to httpPost method in a controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with this method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssociateCaseDetails(string btnSubmit, string navigate)
    {
    ................................
    ................................
    }
```

In the view i had an input like

```
<input type="submit" class="backdetails" value="BACK" name="btnSubmit"  />
```

When i clicked on that button the btnSubmit value was **BACK**, so i thought of creating a similar input which will call that method

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="SAVE" name="btnChangeStatus"  />
```

When i click this the AssociateCaseDetails is getting called but the btnSubmit is having `null` as value
What have i done wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post method has a parameter named `btnSubmit`, so the first submit button works because it has the attribute `name="btnSubmit"`. The second does not work because it has `name="btnChangeStatus"`. Change the second button to have the same `name` attribute (`name="btnSubmit"`) so that it will be bound to your parameter.